# Distance between two foci of an Ellipse

Tags: geometry, proof-writing, conic-sections

The formula for the distance between two foci of an ellipse makes sense. I.e. 2ae is simply a multiple of a2 which accounts for the elliptic curvature; However, I do not feel satisfied just knowing this fact, and I can not find any articles online of a general proof.

could anyone provide a general proof or atleast a link to a general proof?

Known: distance between two foci of an ellipse = 2ae.
Requirement:
Prove that this is true given the definition provided here: https://www.math-only-math.com/ellipse-formulae.html
and the relationship defined by the function $c^2 + b^2 = a^2 $

Comment: It's easier to go the other way: take foci ${F_{1}=(c,\,0),\ F_{2}=(-c,\,0)}$ and write down the equation $PF_1+PF_2=2a$, where $P=(x,y)$. Square and simplify twice to get $${\frac{x^{2}}{a^{2}}}+{\frac{y^{2}}{a^{2}-c^2}}=1.$$

Comment: $ √ ((x + c)^2 + y^2) + √ ((x – c)^2 + y^2) = 2a - √ ((x + c)^2 + y^2)= 4a^2 – 4a√ ((x – c)^2 + y^2) + (x – c)^2 + y^2$

Comment: You forgot to square the LHS. Then simplify and square again. You can find the whole story here: https://www.basic-mathematics.com/derive-the-equation-of-an-ellipse.html

Comment: Very interesting derivation for the equation of an ellipse as a function of its property, i.e. the length of the major axis is equal to the sum of the lengths between a point on the ellipse and the focuses. But, it does not relate e to the distance between focuses, I suppose if you find a supplement for b and a in the eccentricity formula you could solve this.

Comment: Sorry, I probably didn't understand which formula you want to prove. What's your definition of eccentricity?

Comment: @Intelligentipauca I have updated the question with further elaboration.

Comment: Well: $a^2e^2=a^2-b^2=c^2$ by definition. Hence $ae=c$ and that's all.